# C++ template defining number of parameters of function

Tags: c++, templates

Lets say i have a class looking like this

```
template<int n>
class A{
   array<size_t, n> sizes;
   //...
public:
   template <int k>
   A<k> reshape(array<size_t, k> new_sizes){
      return A<k>(new_sizes):
   }
};
```

it works but the parameter `new_sizes` is syntatically suboptimal, since i have to call it like that:

```
foo.reshape(array<size_t, 3>{1,2,3});
```

This does not work:

```
foo.reshape({1,2,3});
```

Is there a way to either define a `initializer_list` with compile time size (so i could use it instead of the array) OR (even better) a way to define the size of a variadic parameter, so i could write something like

```
foo.reshape(1,2,3);
```

Comment: What is `T` used for?

Comment: @TedLyngmo not necessary for the question; i use it internally for the storage of data (its the data type), but you are right, i may as well exclude it from the question.

Comment: Ok, good. I undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> OR (even better) a way to define the size of a variadic parameter, so i could write something like
> `foo.reshape(1,2,3);`

You could take the `sizeof...` a parameter pack:

```cpp
template <size_t N>
class A {
    std::array<size_t, N> sizes;

public:
    A() = default;

    template <class... Args>
    A(Args&&... ss) : sizes{static_cast<size_t>(ss)...} {}

    template <class... Args>
    A<sizeof...(Args)> reshape(Args&&... new_sizes) {
//    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        return A<sizeof...(Args)>(static_cast<size_t>(new_sizes)...);
    }
};

// deduction guide:
template <class... Args>
A(Args&&...) -> A<sizeof...(Args)>;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/14WfPrqWa)

Answer (score 2):

`{1, 2, 3}` has no type but can be deduced as `initializer_list<T>` or `T[N]`

So to keep your syntax, it would be:

```
template <std::size_t K>
A<K> reshape(/*const*/ size_t (&new_sizes)[K])
{
    return A<K>(new_sizes):
}
```

> so i could write something like `foo.reshape(1,2,3);`

For that variadic template:

```
template <typename... Ts>
A<sizeof...Ts> reshape(Ts... elems)
{
    return reshape({elems...}); // using above method
}
```